# nginx location path with proxy_pass

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, gunicorn

I have following problem, i'm trying to put a Django app with an gunicorn server on my VPS running Nginx. My nginx config looks like this:

```
upstream app_name {
    server unix:/path/to/socket/file.sock fail_timeout=10;
}

server {

   listen 80 default_server;
   listen[::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   root /webapps/;
   server_name my_hostname.com;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

   location /appname/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://app_name;

}
```

}

However when i navigate to `my_server.com/appname/` i constantly get 404 error. I'm still new to Nginx, could someone point me in the right direction on how to set the proxy_pass for `/appname/` path? I should point out that when location for `/appname/` is replaced with `/` the django app is running fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need a trailing slash for proxy_pass:

```
proxy_pass http://app_name/;
```

it helps you to cut the "appname" prefix so the config looks like:

```
upstream app_name {
    server unix:/path/to/socket/file.sock fail_timeout=10;
}

server {

   listen 80 default_server;
   listen[::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   root /webapps/;
   server_name my_hostname.com;

   location /appname/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://app_name/;

}
```

Comment: @KonradWąsowicz you are welcome, make also sure you serve images straight through Nginx (by define another location with static assets), it's recommended way.

Comment: I did that, however i got to some strange problem afterwards, namely each time i click a link inside an app it keeps resetting the address to root for instance when i click `login` link instead of going to `hostname.com/appname/login` it redirects to `hostname.com/login`.

Comment: @KonradWąsowicz all in-app redirects needs to be rewritten with URL "/appname" prefix in your case. If it's hard to do, just mount app according to that [example](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath) and remove trailing slash.

Comment: @mikhailov Adding `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/appname'` in *settings.py* worked for me. Thank you.