# Connection betweetn docker containers

Tags: django, nginx

I am struggling with the connection of nginx and django (docker container)

My strategy is like this , 
run uwsgi `http` option and `8001` port. (not socket)

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --module myapp.wsgi --py-autoreload 1 --logto /tmp/mylog.log
```

then I confirmed `wget http://127.0.0.1:8001` works.

but from, `nginx`, It can't connect somehow. `(111: Connection refused)` error

However from nginx `wget http://django:8001` works.

How can I connect between containars

```
upstream django {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

server_tokens off;
```

I am trying this config but, if I try this, my container doesn't launch.

log is like this
`2020/03/24 08:24:04 [emerg] 1#1: upstream "django" may not have port 8001 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app_nginx.conf:16`

```
upstream django {
    ip_hash;
    server django:8001;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://django:8001/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

server_tokens off;
```

my docker compose is very simple...

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/uwsgi_params:/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
      - ./nginx/static:/static
    depends_on:
      - django
```

---

Finally thanks to helps. my server works. final conf is like this below.

remove `upstream` and use name 'django' instead of `127.0.0.1`

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://django:8001/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

server_tokens off;
```

Comment: Do NGINX and uWSGI run in different containers?

Comment: Yes it runes in defferent container but in same service.

Comment: I added the config file for docker service to article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx location path with proxy\_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475021/nginx-location-path-with-proxy-pass)

Comment: I tried but may be not, I update the artilcle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they run in different containers, 127.0.0.1 is not the correct IP; use the name of the other container, e.g.

```
proxy_pass http://django:8001;
```

so Docker's internal DNS can route things.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer might be hit the spot . But when I use `proxy_pass http://django:8001;` my container doesn't launch.

Comment: By the way, you don't need that `upstream` block with a simple `proxy_pass`.